How do we migrate a question?
I recently obtained the administrative tools, but I can't find where I could suggest a migration for a question when it seems it would suit another site better.
Is it normal?

Welcome! When you close a question, it will allow you to move the question to a different site. That is, you don't suggest, you do.

ok but what has to be done when the question is closed? I can't find the link.... maybe I still don't have the right.

@SRKX -- Select "close", then "off topic", then you should have the option to "migrate" to another SE site.

@SRKX -- My guess is that, unless you're a moderator, you can't migrate until you have a higher point count.

I can only suggest META. It's a pitty as I think it would really help getting the right questions on the site.

I also don't see a migrate link, so I don't think it's a function of points.  Perhaps it is mods-only.

@SRKX -- Huh. Maybe nosebleed points? Every now and then I'll go to StackOverflow with a MySQL question and find someone with >100k! I wonder if we can get more mods? Or if I can transfer my mod rights?

@Tal Fishman -- see previous comment (I can only notify one user at a time).

@richardh: I would be really happy to become mod if you think I suit the job and it is possible.

@SRKX I doubt richardh could do it unilaterally, but if the SE team is willing to make it happen, I'd also be really happy to be a mod.  As a mod, I would definitely post fewer negative comments (except for flagrantly off-topic posts) and close fewer questions than I've voted to close so far.

I verified on MSO, only mods can migrate a question, at least for beta sites.

@TalFishman -- Thanks! I asked about mod elections/turnover, but no response, yet (maybe she took the whole week off?). I will ask again if I don't get a response nest week.
